# Convert Bound Method to Decimal

Tags: python, django

(edit added more code)

Keep getting an error here where its asking me to convert bound method to decimal.  I think the problem is this line:

```
order_item = OrderItem(item=item.item_id, quantity=item.quantity, price=item.price, order=order)
```

I think Django wants me to convert item.price into a decimal, but I've been unable to figure out how.  I tried decimal.Decimal(str(item.price)) which didn't work, and float(item.price) didnt work as well.  As always, thanks in advance.

```
#cart.get_cart_items
def get_cart_items(request):
    return Cart.objects.filter(cart_id=_cart_id(request))

#models
class Cart(models.Model):
    cart_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item_id = models.ForeignKey('store.Item', unique=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)
    image1 =  models.ImageField(upload_to='img')
    image2 =  models.ImageField(upload_to='img', blank=True)
    image3 =  models.ImageField(upload_to='img', blank=True)
    image_caption1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    image_caption2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    image_caption3 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    description = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    shipping_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)



#views    
    def express_payment(request):
            user = request.user
            cart_subtotal = cart.cart_subtotal(request)

            if request.method == "POST":
                form = PaymentForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    order = form.save(commit=False)
                    order.buyer = request.user
                    order.transaction_id = "12345678901234567890"
                    order.save()
                    if order.pk:
                        cart_items = cart.get_cart_items(request)
                        for item in cart_items:
                            order_item = OrderItem(item=item.item_id, quantity=item.quantity, price=item.price, order=order)
                            order_item.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more error info, or we just cannot provide any meaning help..

Edit:

Assume that the `class Item` and `OrderItem` is the same thing, then I think `user`, `name`, is required to save a `OrderItem` instance.

Comment: sorry added the views and models